# Node.js/Express: Setting routes after database connection and session setup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express

I want to store the sessions in a `sessions` collection in mongo to have them persist over server restarts.

I am having some trouble understanding how to structure my application to set up session management with `express-session` and [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-mongo).

When setting up sessions like below, `req.session` is `undefined` in my route.

So far, my *app.js* looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var myRoute = require('./routes/myroute');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var collection = 'kittens';
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://user_mongoadmin:blabla>@localhost:20742/"+collection,
    {auth:{authdb:"admin"}},
    function(e) {
        console.log('database connecterino');
        app.use(cookieParser)
        app.use(session({
            secret: 'wombatlover95',
            store: new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection })
        }));

        app.listen();
    }
);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/myroute/', myRoute);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

With *routes/myroute.js* being:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();  

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.session);
    // returns undefined

});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the order in which I am stating the database connection, the session setup in my routes. But I just can't seem to understand how exactly I would structure my application here.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot in advance!

**edit:** I switched to [mongoose-session](https://github.com/TheRealCharDev/mongoose-session) which seems to work nicely. I will wait some time in case the actual problem in this question gets solved, else I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup for your mongoose and mongo-session-store should be as followed:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var connectMongo = require('connect-mongo')({ session: session });

    mongoose.connect('your connect');

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use(session({
                        resave           : true,
                        saveUninitialized: true,
                        secret           : 'yourSecret',
                        store            : new connectMongo({
                                                                url           : config.mongoConnect,
                                                                auto_reconnect: true
                                                            })
                    }));
app.listen(3000);
```

First of all it's not necessary to `require` the `express-session` after the initial setup - you can remove it from your routers. I believe that you're facing a bad timed situation that your callback comes before the other part of your middleware or it's bad ordered with your body and cookie parser. `app.listen()` should be the last thing that happens.

Here is another [tutorial](http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/06/node-tutorial-5/)  on this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! However: I can't use the `url` parameter in connectMongo because I have to connect with an auth database (see `mongoose.connect("mongodb://user_mongoadmin:blabla>@localhost:20742/"+collection,
    {auth:{authdb:"admin"}} [...])`)

Comment: I tried arranging the code as you suggested and passing the existing connection like I did before with `mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection` but that gives me the same error.

Comment: `Mongo-connect`supports auths (https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)

Are you using `mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection[0]` as mentioned in the documentation of express-session?

Comment: Now yes, and I think I managed to work setting up sessions by doing so in the callback that is executed when the db connection was successful. However, now in my routes, session is `undefined`. I assume that is because they are defined at the wrong place but I can't figure out a working solution. Putting them in the db callback too makes them return a 404.

Comment: What happens in your mongo database? There should be another collection named 'sessions' with your current session cookie.

Comment: I left off this problem and switched to mongoose-session so unfortunately I cant tell anymore. However, I'll mark this as answered. Thank you for your help.